# Selenium Chrome Webdriver Version "Not Supported"?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting some odd behavior out of the Selenium Webdriver. My python script was working LITERALLY yesterday, and today I am getting this message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76
```

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

And it appears to be finding version 76 so I dont understand what it is complaining about...

```
Checking for win32 chromedriver:76.0.3809.68 in cache
Driver found in C:\Users\User\.wdm\chromedriver\76.0.3809.68\win32/chromedriver.exe
```

And it looks like I'm not the only one having this issue, but I am not seeing a solution. 
See [this](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/349)

Does anyone have any advice on how to troubleshoot this? Is there a way to specific a version to download to the ChromeDriverManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Google launched a new version of Chrome 24hrs ago and that the webdrivermanager default to the newest version. After updating Chrome to the latest version, the script works again. Phew! Go to Help->About Chrome->Update and that should solve the issue, if you are facing it.